# Updating some fields implicitly when update in Slick?

Tags: slick

I am using Slick 3.2 in my Scala application.

In my application, all the tables have `created_at` and `updated_at` as their fields.
For example the `users` table have `created_at` and `updated_at`.

I want to update `updated_at` implicitly when I update these tables through Slick implementing an extension method.

Is there a way to implement such method?

```scala
package com.example

object Main {
  import slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile.api._
  import java.time.Instant
  import slick.jdbc.JdbcType
  import java.sql.Timestamp

  implicit val instantColumnType: JdbcType[Instant] with BaseTypedType[Instant] = ??? // definition is omitted.

  case class User(id: Int, name: String, mail: String, createdAt: Instant, updatedAt: Instant)

  abstract class AppTable[T](tag: Tag, tableName: String) extends Table[T](tag, tableName) {
    def createdAt = column[Instant]("created_at")
    def updatedAt = column[Instant]("updated_at")
  }

  class UserTable(tag: Tag) extends AppTable[User](tag, "users") {
    def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    def name = column[String]("name")
    def mail = column[String]("mail")

    def * = (id, name, mail, createdAt, updatedAt) <> ((User.apply _).tupled, User.unapply)
  }

  val users: TableQuery[UserTable] = ??? // instantiation of users is omitted.

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    // This needs to execute SQL like
    // UPDATE users SET name = 'foo', mail = 'bar@example.com', updated_at = '2019-06-02T02:27:43'
    users
      .filter(record => record.id === 42)
      .updateExtra(
        record => (record.name, record.mail),
        ("foo", "bar@example.com"),
      )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the solution you're looking for, but I'd push this functionality to the database using a trigger. Probably possible to define within Slick, but most likely even easier to just use the SQL. something like this

```
create trigger before update on users 
for each row
set NEW.updated_at = UTC_TIMESTAMP
end;
```